# Are the following statements true? Linear algebra, linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

i,If $[v_{1},v_{2}...v_{n}]=\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then $v_{1},v_{2}...v_{n}$is a linear independt vector system

ii,If $v_{1},v_{2}...v_{n}$is a linear independt vector system,then $[v_{1},v_{2}...v_{n}]=\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Where $[v_{1},v_{2}...v_{n}]=\{c_{1}v_{1}+c_{2}v_{2}+...+c_{n}v_{n}:c_{1},c_{2}...c_{n} \in\mathbb{R}\}$, so this is the linear combination

I think that $i$, is false, because a linear dependent system can give us also $\mathbb{R}$

And I think that $ii$, is true because a linear independent system gives us exactly $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: For n vectors in an n-dimensional space being linearly independent is the same as spanning the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both true. More generally, for any $k$,

1. If $[v_{1},v_{2}...v_{k}]=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (with $k\ge n$), then some subset consisting of $n$ many of the $v_{1},v_{2}...v_{k}$ form a linearly independent vector system.
2. If $v_{1},v_{2}...v_{k}$ is a linearly independent vector system ($k\le n$),then $[v_{1},v_{2}...v_{k}]$ is a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.